# pattern matching and delete all the lines except the last occurence

Tags: unix

I have a txt file which is having 100+ lines, i want to search for pattern and delete all the lines except the last occurrence.

Here are the lines from the txt file.

my pattern search is "string1=" , "string2=", "string3=" , "string4=" and "string5="

```
string1=hi
string2=hello
string3=welcome
string3=welcome1
string3=
string4=hi
string5=hello
```

i want to go through the each line and keep "string3=" is empty on the file and remove the "string3=welcome" ,"string3=welcome1"

please help me.

Comment: You will have to write a program to do this. Share the program you've written so far and tell us where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For a single pattern, you can start with something like this:

```
grep "string3" input | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %h;

while (<STDIN>) {
  my ($k, $v) = split /=/;
  $h{$k} = $v;
  }

foreach my $k ( sort keys %h ) {
  print "$k=$h{$k}";
  }
```

The perl script here will take your list as stdin and process output as you mention.  This assumes you want the keys (string*) as sorted output.

If you only wants the values that start with string1-5 only then you can put a match in the beginning of your while loop as so:

```
next if ! /^string[1-5]=/;
```